# How to transfer a text file from smartwatch to smartphone using android studio?

Tags: android-studio, wear-os, file-transfer, data-layers, wearables

I basically have created a text file in my smartwatch. I want to transfer it to my smartphone using android studio. How can I do it? Can somebody please provide me with the code segment to do this. I am really stuck at this. Any help would be highly appreciated.